# how on elasticsearch to do a range filter using the "REST request URI"?

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

I have this simple data on ES::

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/dt/art/1 -d '{ "age": 77 }'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/dt/art/2 -d '{ "age": 19 }'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/dt/art/3 -d '{ "age": 42 }'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/dt/art/4 -d '{ "age": 33 }'
```

Is it possible to do a range filter on the "age" using the "[REST request URI](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-uri-request.html)"?

For now, I only get this with the "[REST request body](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-request-body.html)":

```
$ curl "localhost:9200/dt/art/_search?pretty" -d'{
    "query": {
      "bool": { "must": { "match_all": {} },
                "filter": {
                  "range": {
                  "age": { "gte": 20, "lte": 50}}}}}}'


{ "took" : 8, "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : { "total" : 5, "successful" : 5, "skipped" : 0, "failed" : 0 },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      { "_index" : "dt", "_type" : "art", "_id" : "4", "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : { "age" : 33 } },
      { "_index" : "dt", "_type" : "art", "_id" : "3", "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : { "age" : 42 } }
    ]
  }
}
$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
GET dt/art/_search?q=age:[19+TO+50]
```

For dates you can use something like this

```
_search?q=metrictype:os+datetime:[\"2016-08-30 10:00:00\"+to+\"2016-08-30 10:30:00\" ]+fields:datetime,cpu,disk"
```